# URLSessionDownloadDelegate didFinishDownloadingTo not called in background

Tags: ios, background-process, appdelegate, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I start a download in an action extension (`ActionRequestHandler`) like this:

```
private lazy var urlSession: URLSession = {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "de.stefantrauth.Downloader")
    config.sharedContainerIdentifier = "group.de.stefantrauth.Downloader"
    return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
}()

private func initiateDownloadOfFileFrom(url: URL) {
    urlSession.downloadTask(with: url).resume()
    completeRequest() // this tells the system the action extension is done with its work
}
```

Then the download is processed by iOS in the background.

I now want to handle the finished download in my main application `AppDelegate`, because that is what iOS calls when the download has finished.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession")
    urlSessionBackgroundCompletionHandler = completionHandler
}
```

This method gets called in background after some time as expected.

My `AppDelegate` also implements `URLSessionDelegate` and `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` to process updates for the download.

Especially interesting are

```
func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("urlSessionDidFinishEvents")
        self.urlSessionBackgroundCompletionHandler?()
        self.urlSessionBackgroundCompletionHandler = nil
    }
}
```

and

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("download finished to \(location.absoluteString)")
    do {
        let documentsURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let savedURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(location.lastPathComponent)
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: savedURL)
        print("moved file to: \(savedURL.absoluteString)")
    } catch {
        print ("file error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Both `urlSessionDidFinishEvents` and `didFinishDownloadingTo` **are not being called after `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` got called in background**. Only after relaunching the app into foreground the delegate methods get called.

Why are they not getting called and what can I do to fix that?

I tried creating the `URLSession` in `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`like this:

```
private func initUrlSessionWith(identifier: String) {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: identifier)
    config.sharedContainerIdentifier = "group.de.stefantrauth.Downloader"
    urlSession = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession")
    initUrlSessionWith(identifier: identifier)
    urlSessionBackgroundCompletionHandler = completionHandler
}
```

However this did not fix the problem.

Before you ask: Yes I am testing this on a real device because the simulator has problems with background task handling.

Comment: I have a feeling this problem is specific to extensions, because the code looks fine to me; this is probably a Quinn question.  Ask on the developer forums.  In terms of general tips, there's no reason to run the session callbacks on the main thread; you're already dispatching the one critical callback onto the main thread.  Just pass nil.  But I'm pretty sure that isn't the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My code is actually correct. Just my way of debugging was the problem. After using console logging instead of debugging via Xcode it was working fine.

See https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/263807#263807 for more details on how to work with background url session debugging.